# Hiding css dropdown menu on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

In the navigation bar, on click of "Home 3" menu, a dropdown menu appears through jQuery. I want to hide this menu when I hover on other links of the menu for which I have included style as below:

```
.nav-ul .menu-item:hover ul{
    display:none;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/1/

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible using pure CSS.

Comment: It can't be accomplished with CSS in general case. But for your specific markup there is a trick http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/13/

Comment: @YuryTarabanko What changes did you make in the fiddle ?

Comment: @user2585299 css line 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `.nav-ul .menu-item:hover ul` will only target the `<ul>` inside the `.menu-item` item being hovered.

You can't traverse up the `DOM` using CSS as of now.

Add the following script:

```
$('.menu-item').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('ul').hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/6/)

**Update:**

If you want to hide the dropdown when the mouse moves away, you can use the second callback of hover, as given below:

```
$('.menu-item').hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('ul').hide();
},

function () {
    $(this).find('ul').hide()
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/22/)

*Side note:* For anyone down voting seeing [Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351705/yury-tarabanko)'s comment, it's [not a reliable solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/18/) for the task at hand (*it doesn't work if the submenu is before the hovered item*).

Answer (score 1):

Try with jQuery's mouseenter:

```
$(function () {
    $(".nav-header .nav-ul .menu-item .menu-item-link").click(function (link) {
        if (link.currentTarget.text === 'Home 3') {
            $(this).next("ul").css('display', 'block');
        }
        link.stopPropagation();
    }).mouseenter(function () {
        $(".nav-header .nav-ul .menu-item ul:visible").css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/12/)

Comment: Your solution also hides the dropdown when I hover on Home 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
$(".nav-header .nav-ul .menu-item").hover(function (){
        $(".menu-item").each(function(){
            if($(this).find("ul").css("display") == "block")
                $(this).find("ul").css("display","none");
        });
    })
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/21/)..

**EDIT:** I shouldn't used .menu-item-link, just edited the JSFiddle too. Everything works fine.. Thank you for pointing out my mistake..

Comment: Your solution hides the dropdown menu when I am hovering over the sub menus.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will open the sub-menu with a click and close the sub-menu when you move away from either the header or the sub-menu.

I gave each header item an id

```
<li class="menu-item" id="3">
```

Then:

```
$(function(){
   $("#3").click(function(){
     $(".nav-ul .menu-item ul").css('display', 'block');
   });
   $("#3").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".nav-ul .menu-item ul").css('display', 'none');
   });
});
```

Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw44R/20/